# type inference and string literals, how to do it?

Tags: scala, type-inference, literals, string-literals

How do I get this to compile?

**Code**

```
object Playground2 {

  trait Client[S,A] {
    def wrap[S,A](v: A): (S,A)
  }

  class TestClient extends Client[String, Int] {
    override def wrap[String,Int](v: Int): (String, Int) = ("cache 2.00", v)
  }
}
```

**Error** *type mismatch;  found   : java.lang.String("cache 2.00")  required: String*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version of the code that compiles:

```
object Playground2 {

  trait Client[S,A] {
    def wrap(v: A): (S,A)
  }

  class TestClient extends Client[String, Int] {
    override def wrap(v: Int) = ("cache 2.00", v)
  }
}
```

You duplicated the types again in the `wrap` function and you did not need to as they were already defined on the trait itself.

Comment: upsy. you are right. the trait had already declared the types. thx